# What does the .. in #include "../somefile.h" mean

Tags: c++, include, c-preprocessor

Does it mean search the previous folder for somefile.h or the project folder for somefile.h?

Comment: Don't ever use this in new code and change it if you can in old code.  Using relative paths (../whatever) has terrible scalability issues.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It means that look for `somefile.h` in the parent folder with respect to the source file where the include directive is found.

In *nix systems(thats where this convention came from AFAIK):

```
.        manse the current directory.
..       means one level up from the current directory.
```

For example, if you have the following directories structure:

```
home
   |
   code
      | src
      | someOtherDirectory
```

Your source file could be in `home/code/src` and you have:

```
#include "../somefile.h"
```

in your source code, then the compiler is going to look for `somefile.h` in `home/code/`

Comment: @Kip Didn't DOS get that convention from oldish Unix systems also?

Comment: Minor note - this isn't required by the standard to be the meaning of "..", it's just what it means in practice in pretty much any filesystem.

Comment: Yeah, I think so. I was just pointing out that it works that way in DOS too, as the statement "In *nix systems" makes it sound like it is unique to those systems.

Answer (score 3):

It means look in the parent directory for "somefile.h", relative to the directory the file containing the directive is in.

Answer (score 2):

It means the parent directory of the directory the source file is in.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your source files are in `/src`, then `somefile.h` should be above `src` or in `/`